# Value of a and b in f(x) = a sin bx in order to define density function

Tags: probability-theory

I have a density function f(x) = a sin(bx) when 0<=x<=1 .  I have to define the values of a and b so that this becomes a density function . How can I find the values from this function ? Is there any way ? I can solve this problem if I have one unknown variable in this equation .

Comment: What is the range of values of $x$? It cannot be all $x$, sometimes this is negative except in the trivial cases $a=0$ or $b-0$, when it is not a density either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can choose $a$ negative. In that case $b$ will have to be negative. That is not a reasonable choice, but it is legal.

So what conditions do we need? The density function has to be non-negative. That forces 
$$|b|\le \pi.\tag{1}$$ 
This is because if for example $b\gt \pi$, and $a\gt 0$, then our function will be negative when we are a little past $\pi$, and a density function cannot ever be negative.

In addition, we need 
$$\int_0^1 a\sin(bx)\,dx=1.$$
Evaluate. We get
$$\frac{a}{b}\left(1-\cos b\right)=1.\tag{2}$$
That can be rewritten in various ways.

Any pair $(a,b)$ that satisfies Conditions (1) and (2) will yield a legitimate density function. There are infinitely many such pairs.

If further conditions are given for our random variable, such as specifying the mean, we will be able to solve for $a$ and $b$.